# Lebesgue measure of a set of real numbers well-approximated by rationals

Tags: measure-theory, diophantine-approximation

Consider the set $A$ of real numbers $r$ such that there exists a constant $C$ and sequence $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ of rational numbers (where $p_n$ and $q_n$ are integers) with $q_n \rightarrow \infty$ and

$$\left\vert r - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \right\vert < \frac{C}{q_n^3}.$$

How do I show the Lebesgue measure of $A$ is zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets begin by noticing that we only have to concern ourselves with $r\in [0, 1]$: any number that can be so approximated will differ by an an integer from a number in that interval. Now, consider the sets
$$A_q = \left[0, \frac{C}{q^3} \right) \cup \left( 1 - \frac{C}{q^3},  1 \right]\cup \bigcup_{i=1}^{q-1} \left( \frac{i}{q} - \frac{C}{q^3},  \frac{i}{q} + \frac{C}{q^3} \right).$$
Let $x$ be a point satisying the condition, with the sequence $\{q_i\}$ as in the hypothesis. Note that $x \in A_{q_n}$ for all $n$, so we can say that all points satisfying the condition must be in an infinite number of sets of the form $A_q$. Put in terms of sets, this is saying that if$$ B_n = \bigcup_{q=n}^\infty A_q $$then the set of points satisfying the hypothesis in $[0, 1]$ is a subset of $$ X = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n.$$ To get the result, note that $\lambda(A_q) \leq 2C/q^2$, $\lambda(B_n) \leq 2C \sum_{i=n}^\infty 1/i^2$ and so $$\lambda(X) < \liminf_n B_n = 0$$ as required.

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand why "A point satisying the condition must be in an infinite number of sets of the form $A_q$"? Can you explain it more rigorously?

Comment: @FactorY, as requested, I've added an explanatory clause, preceding that sentence.

Comment: Thank you! I got it.